# Funcion con parametros erroneos en c#

Tags: c#, function

Hola qué tal? tengo un problema con una función, al enviar los parámetros estos me dan el error de:

> CS1737    Los parámetros opcionales deben aparecer después de todos los
> parámetros necesarios Principal

El código de la función es el siguiente:

```
public filtrofecha(ref ToolStrip barraaagregar0, string campodefiltro = "", [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(null)] ref DateTimePicker horas01, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(null)] ref DateTimePicker horas02, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(null)] ref ComboBox tiempo0)
        {
```

El error aparece a partir de horas01 como lo muestra la imagen:
[image: Error mostrado por Visual Studio 2019]

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este problema? y a que se debe? espero que alguien me pueda responder gracias.

Comment: los parametros que son opcionales van al final de tu funcion, tu los tienes al principio, en otras palabras primero debes poner los parametros que no son opcionales y despues los que son opcionales

Comment: Eso, lose, pero si vez bien está correcto el orden cierto? por eso no entiendo el error, al principio están los no opcionales, y por ende luego siguen los opcionales. Creo haberlo hecho en buen orden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error se debe a que tienes esta variable que tiene un valor por defecto `string campodefiltro = "",`, debes ponerla después de `horas01`.